# python variable memory size - error

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, memory

I am new in python programming : and I am trying to solve this problem : http://codeforces.com/contest/791/problem/A
- but, when I tried to solve it in my editor it gives me : problem in statement:
"x *= 3", and the interpreter error is : 
line 6, in main
    x *= 3
MemoryError

```
def main():
    x = input("inter first number : ")
    z = input("inter second number : ")
    result = 0
    while x <= z:
        x *= 3
        z *= 2
        result += 1
    print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `x` and `y` are strings, multiplication on strings does `'10'*3 == '101010'` and you probably create an infinite loop, creating larger and larger strings, until you run out of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input` type is `str`: you must convert inputs to numerical values, `int` or `float` prior to applying numerical operations `(*=)`on them::

```
def main():
    x = int(input("inter first number : "))  # alternatively: float(input("inter first number : "))
    z = int(input("inter second number : ")) # same alternative
    result = 0
    while x <= z:
        x *= 3
        z *= 2
        result += 1
    print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

> As @juanpa.arrivillaga pointed out in the comments, the reason for
>   `MemoryError` is that `x` and `y` are strings, multiplication on
>   strings does `'10'*3 == '101010'` and you probably create an infinite
>   loop, creating larger and larger strings, until you run out of memory.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque , additional question. where is to run above code so that it is necessary to convert the input? Because when I ran it on notebook, it didn't raise the error. And when I inserted `type(x)`, the output was `int`. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you did, but the type of `input` is always `str` (in jupyter notebook too)